# Use external email provider instead AWS Cognito to send the user confirmation email

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/@moedano.t/redirect-to-your-website-after-confirm-registration-using-aws-cognito-and-cloud-formation-5c50ff15ff56) to customize email confirmation and redirect user to a specific url.

Now I would handle this email through an email automation tool, so my purpose was to suppress cognito email and send confirmation email through external provider (specifying confirmation link to render in that email).

Is there any way to block cognito email keeping the same confirmation flow?